# Auth::id() is null in Laravel api requests

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, and I've just set up my authentication using `php artisan make:auth`. I'm building a learning portal, and I'm trying to create a Subject against a user, but I'm not certain how to access the id of the current user correctly. I've been looking at similar issues are there seem to be numerous ways of writing authenticated calls, but I'm in uncertain of the best method. However, in my example,`Auth::id()` returns null. Can anyone advise on the best method of doing authenticated api calls?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Subject;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('subjects', function(){
    $subjects = Subject::with(['topics','topics.modules'])->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

    return $subjects;
});

Route::post('subjects', function(Request $data){
    if(isset($data->id)){
        $req = Subject::findOrFail($data->id);
        $req->update(['title'=>$data->title, 'subtitle'=>$data->subtitle]);
    }else{
        $new = Subject::create(['user_id'=> Auth::id(), 'title'=>$data->title, 'subtitle'=>$data->subtitle]);
        return $new->id;
    }
});

Route::delete('subjects/{id}', function($id){
    Subject::where('id', $id)->delete();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the rest of your routes through the `auth:api` middleware. Right now only your `/user` route is using it.

You can apply the middleware to a group of routes like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

    Route::get(...);
    Route::get(...);
    Route::get(...);
});
```

Comment: I'm now getting a 401 on the GET with the message `Unauthorised`.

Comment: That's good. Now you need to make sure you're including the correct Authorization header so that your user will be logged in

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Can you direct me to some relevant documentation?

Comment: @ChrisWickham I would start here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#introduction

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `->where('user_id', Auth::id())` with `->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)`

Also, you might not get the object if you are not inside an auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { ... }
```

Comment: I get `"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"` on the GET request

Comment: Try putting the GET route inside a route group w/ middleware auth like in the answer or in api auth, depending on your need

Answer (score 0):

In the subjects route you are not forcing user to be authenticated. You should use Auth::check() to determine if there is authenticated user or not, and then get that user by using Auth::user()